# post parameter not injectable

Tags: sql, forms, code-injection

I want to understand why its not possible to inject sql statements in the form POST parameters. I tried it with sqlmap and manually without success.

There is a defined function:

```
function mysql_get_result($sQuery, $hSocket) //$sQuery: mysql query, 
                                          $hSocket:MySQLSocket(mysql_connect).  
{
 $sResource = mysql_query($sQuery, $hSocket);
 list($sValue) = mysql_fetch_row($sResource);
 return $sValue;
}
```

and there is the actual query for the POST parameter:

```
(mysql_get_result("SELECT place FROM towns
 WHERE place = '".$sR_place."' AND num = '".$iR_num."'", $hMySQLSocket) 
 == $sR_place and $sR_place != '')
```

No input sanitiazion at all. So why isnt it working ? Does sql injection only work when its mysql_query function without more steps to do?

Answer (score 1):

Your code should vulnerable to SQL injection, since you're not sanitizing with `mysql_real_escape_string`, or parameterizing the query.

You should try revising your POST parameters, because the issue is most likely that your attack isn't properly formatted.  [Try a variety of attacks](http://old.justinshattuck.com/2007/01/18/mysql-injection-cheat-sheet/).